# C program using sprintf()/write() has extra characters

Tags: c, printf, fwrite

I'm writing a C program where a user inputs 10 integers into an array, and the program outputs the reverse of that array on the console as well as writing it to a file. The only issue with my program is that in both outputs, there are extra characters. In the console, there is a "%" before the first integer. In the file I write to, there are two empty boxes in front of every integer except the first one (and also on a new line after the last integer.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int i;
  int input;
  char *filename = "/home/privateinfo/5/output";
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));
  int *tenInts = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

  /* open the file for writing */
  int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);

  if (fd < 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  /* read ten integers from keyboard and store in array*/
  write(1, "Enter 10 integers:\n", 20) ;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &input);
    tenInts[i] = input;
  }

  write(1, "\nThe integers reversed are:\n", 30);

  /* print array in reverse and write to file*/
  for (i = 9; i > -1; i--) {
    sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", tenInts[i]);
    write(1, buffer, sizeof(int));
    if(write(fd, buffer, sizeof(int)+1) < 0) {
      write(2, "There was an error writing to the file.\n", 50);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  /* close the file and clear pointer */
  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

[Here is my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOSk9.jpg)

Comment: There is no correlation between the length of `buffer` and `sizeof(int)`. You cannot `write` an `int` to `stdout` (e.g. with `write(1, buffer, sizeof(int));` -- how many bytes does `"4312981"` take?), you can `fputs (buffer, stdout);` (you could simply `puts(buffer)` but you included the `'\n'` in `buffer` (for some strange reason). Don't `return -1;` to the shell. `return 1;` to indicate error. You cannot correctly use any input function (like `scanf("%d", &input);`) unless you ***check the return***.

Comment: `"Enter 10 integers:\n"` is only `19` characters, not `20`, `"\n"` is a single character (ASCII 10, 0xa).

Comment: I changed the write calls to use strlen(buffer) instead of what I was doing previously. I also removed the "\n" from the buffer. These two fixes solved it for me, thank you. I'm a bit new so idk if there's a way to mark a comment as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is you fail to allocate sufficient storage for `buffer` and most likely invoke *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to store more characters than you have room for in `buffer`. You additionally invoke *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to `write` more characters to `stdout` than you have characters for (you are *off-by-one* (or more) in your count of characters in the string literals because `"\n"` is one-character (the *newline* character, ASCII `10`, or `0xa`), not multiple characters of `'\'` and `'n'`.

Unfortunately, that is but the tip of the iceberg. First, as couple of notes, avoid hardcoding *Magic-Numbers* in your code (`10` is a *Magic-Number*) and avoid hardcoding Filenames). If you need to change a number like `10` because you want `11` integers, look how many changes are necessary. If you want to write to a different file, you have to re-compile your code. Instead:

```
#define NINT     10   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define INTCHARS 32   /* adequate for LLONG_MIN or ULLONG_MAX (20+1 chars) */
#define FCRMODE  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH
```

Now you have a single place to change a constant at the top of your code should you need to make a change.

For your filename, you can provide a default, but your program takes argument for `main` when it is declared as:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
```

Pass the filename in as an argument to your program or use the hardcoded filename as a default - only. Example:

```
    char *filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/home/privateinfo/5/output";
```

If an argument is provided it is used as the filename, otherwise, your default is used.

In your allocation of:

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

You only allocate 4-bytes to `buffer` that means at maximum you can only store 3-digits and the *nul-terminating* character, or since you also include the `'\n'` character, you can store no more than a 2-digit number. Instead, there is no reason to allocate for buffer. The longest `long long int` or `unsigned long long` on a 64-bit computer is 20-characters (including the `'-'` minus sign) `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character for a total of 21-characters needed. Simply define a 32-byte buffer and you can include your `'\n'` with 10-characters of safety, e.g.

```
    char buffer[INTCHARS] = "";
```

Next, don't count characters for `write`. If you a printing *String-Literals*, simply using `strlen()` will give you to proper number of characters to output. Or, if you need to create a string to write with `sprintf`, ***save the return*** it tells you how many characters where written to the buffer (not including the *nul-terminating* character), e.g.

```
    /* read NINT integers from keyboard and store in array*/
    nchar = sprintf (buffer, "Enter %d integers:\n", NINT);
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nchar);       /* (or simply use printf) */
```

(why you are using `write` is a mystery when you can simply `printf` the string with the conversion directly to `stdout`)

Don't return **negative** values to the shell. POSIX requires that only positive values are returned. That is why the macro `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined as `1`.

The rest remainder of the errors are just additional incorporations of what is discussed above. Putting it altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NINT     10   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define INTCHARS 32   /* adequate for LLONG_MIN or ULLONG_MAX (20+1 chars) */
#define FCRMODE  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int fd, i, input, nchar, *tenInts;
    char *filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/home/privateinfo/5/output";
    char buffer[INTCHARS] = "";

    if (!(tenInts = malloc (NINT * sizeof *tenInts))) {
        perror ("malloc-tenInts");
        return 1;
    }

    /* open the file for writing */
    if ((fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, FCRMODE)) < 0) {
        perror ("fopen-filename");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read NINT integers from keyboard and store in array*/
    nchar = sprintf (buffer, "Enter %d integers:\n", NINT);
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nchar);       /* (or simply use printf) */

    for (i = 0; i < NINT; i++) {
        if (scanf ("%d", &input) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        tenInts[i] = input;
    }

    write (STDOUT_FILENO, "\nThe integers reversed are:\n",
            strlen ("\nThe integers reversed are:\n"));

    /* print array in reverse and write to file*/
    for (i = NINT-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        nchar = sprintf (buffer, "%d\n", tenInts[i]);
        write (STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nchar);
        if (write (fd, buffer, nchar) < 0) {
            write (STDERR_FILENO, "There was an error writing to the file.\n",
                    strlen ("There was an error writing to the file.\n"));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* ALWAYS validate close of file (after a write) */
    if (close (fd) == -1)
        perror ("close-fd");

    return 0;
}
```

Now you won't have any funny boxes output (a good indication of *Undefined Behavior*) when you run your code.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tenintwrite dat/tenintwrite.txt
Enter 10 integers:
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

The integers reversed are:
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
```

**Output File**

```
$ cat dat/tenintwrite.txt
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.